# Live-USB with read-write stick

Tags: live-usb

I've got one of the few USB Sticks with hardware read only switch (Trekstor). I'd like to use a bootable Linux with it, e.g. to fix problems with Windows PCs without danger of infecting or changing the stick's contents.

However, for installing updates or new software on it in a safe environment, it should be possible to write to the stick when the switch is on write enabled.

I'm not sure how switching form one mode to the other is internally done. Any experience with such a kind of drive and how to configure live-USB in this case?

If restart is required to change the writing mode, this would be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Live USBs are not intended for installing updates and new software. Their main purposes are hardware testing, software evaluation and the system installation. Some persistent storage is offered as an option for saving personal files and settings. You really don't need a USB stick with a hardware switch to run Ubuntu from. As for fixing Windows, I rather doubt Ubuntu is the best tool for the job.

Comment: Tried my best, buddy. :)

Comment: sorry I came off a bit harsh there :P

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions which Linux distribution would better suit this use case than Ubuntu?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. You can run malware scans from Ubuntu, or copy files from an unbootable system, but actually fixing Windows registry errors or programs' malfunctions is simply not what Ubuntu is designed for. Honestly, I don't know if any Linux distro is.

Comment: I thought a quite versatile approach, meaning what you describe (copy from and maybe write to NTFS, Malware scan) but also just access the Internet, partition hard drive, usage in internet cafes, etc. So a "normal" Ubuntu would be ok I think except that it must be bootable from USB and I'd like to write my own personal files on it, but I'd also like to be able to use it in read-only mode.

Comment: I thought you said 'fixing problems with Windows PCs'. What problem did you have in mind? Booting your own OS in internet cafes might upset the owners. It'll probably disrupt their billing systems and what not. As for the read only part, I am pretty sure that the Live USB file system is already read only, and if the hardware switch works, I guess that would make it read only+. As said above, you can set aside some persistent storage that is writable.

Comment: So what happens if I use the live USB and enables the persistent storage, but then have the switch to read only? Can I use my stick at all or does there need to be a RAM drive for stuff like Firefox cache files and similar files that have to be writable?

Comment: Naturally, when the switch is on, I'd expect write jobs to the disk to fail. In other words, you might get an error when trying to copy files from RAM to USB. A RAM disk is creation doesn't seem to be relevant to a flash drive write protection.

Comment: You can change the command line options at bootup time. Add `persistence` if you are going to use it, and remove it if you want to use it in read-only mode (but then it'll work as if you haven't used persistence at all). Or maybe you can try Puppy Linux. It asks if you want to save changes or not at shutdown time instead of startup time.